# sinatraでes6やjsxのコードをトランスパイルしてレンダリングしたい

Tags: sinatra, es6

sinatraでは`erb`などのメソッドを利用することで、簡単に`views`ディレクトリに配置したテンプレートファイルを出力することができますが、es6やjsxのコードをトランスパイルしたコードを同じような形で出力したいと思っています。

```
get 'script.js' do
  babel :script
end
```

sinatraの公式ドキュメントを読みますと、[オリジナルテンプレートエンジンの追加](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro-ja.html#%E3%82%AA%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B8%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AB%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E3%83%97%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%82%A8%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B8%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E8%BF%BD%E5%8A%A0)の項目がありますので、無理な実装であるということはないと思っています。

また、sinatraではテンプレートエンジンのレンダリングにtiltを使っているようで、[tiltのgithub](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt)を閲覧してみると、es6やjsxのレンダリングに対応している様子が見受けられました。

これをうまく利用することで要望を満たすことができるのではないかと思い、両者のドキュメントを確認しながら以下のコードを作成しました。

Gemfile

```
gem "sinatra", "~> 1.4.7"
gem "sinatra-contrib", "~> 1.4.7"
gem "slim", "~> 3.0.7"
gem "sass", "~> 3.4.22"
gem "babel-transpiler", "~> 0.7.0"
```

app.rb

```
# coding: utf-8
require 'sinatra'
require 'sinatra/reloader'
require 'slim'
require 'sass'
require 'tilt/babel'

helpers do
  def babel(*args) render(:babel, *args) end
end

get '/style/main' do sass :'style/main' end
get '/script/main' do babel :'script/main' end
```

views/script/main.es6

```
alert('test')
```

実際はもう少し複雑なコードだったのですが、投稿用に余計な部分は削除させていただきました。

上記のコードで`http://example.com/style/main`にアクセスするとsassがトランスパイルされてcssがクライアントサイドから取得できるのが確認できます。

しかし、独自にhelperで実装した`babel`メソッドを実装したルーティングにアクセスすると次のようなエラーメッセージが返ってきます。

```
"\xEF" on US-ASCII
```

sinatraもtiltもあまり深く触ったことがないので探り探りの実装になってしまっているのですが、どうやら`views/script/main.es6`のファイルを`main.babel`や`main.jsx`以外の拡張子にリネームするとエラー内容が以下に変わりますので、tiltがes6ファイルをトランスパイルしようとしているような様子は確認できました。

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /var/www/vhosts/test-project/views/script/main.babel
```

`main.es6`ファイルの文字コードに問題があるような気がしているのですが、emacs上の表記では`-UUU`となっていますので、UTF-8に設定されていることが確認できます。

何が問題なのか指摘箇所などありましたら是非アドバイスいただければと思っています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`config.ru`に`Encoding.default_external = 'UTF-8'`を追加したらエラーが出なくなりました。